# Meaning of そのすきに

Tags: meaning, words

I would like to know the meaning of **そのすきに** in the following sentence:

> そのすきに、何者かが忍び入って、大金を持ち去ったものにちがいない。

Context: Some money has disappeared, and every employee is looking for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[隙]{すき} usually refers to a gap for someone to take advantage of. Unlike [隙間]{すきま}, it is rarely used to mean a gap in space. In this particular context, it refers to some gap period during which something was not done, for example, someone was not paying attention to something when they were supposed to be. To understand what exactly その refers to, we would need to know what was said before that line.